# screen magnification for the visually impaired using Java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, zooming

Is there any way to create a feature which allows a user to toggle screen magnification if they are visually impaired.

I'm asking in context of a program like eclipse, where a user who is visually impaired can toggle on and off a feature which magnifies the text, icons and navigation bar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use this short code for a general magnifier when cropping images.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

class ZoomOnMouse {

    Robot robot;
    int zoomFactor = 2;
    PointerInfo pi;
    JPanel gui;
    JLabel output;
    Timer t;

    public ZoomOnMouse() throws AWTException {
        robot = new Robot();
        gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2, 2));
        output = new JLabel("Point at something to see it zoomed!");
        gui.add(output, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        final int size = 256;
        final BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
                size, size, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        final JLabel zoomLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi));
        gui.add(zoomLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        MouseListener factorListener = new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (zoomFactor == 2) {
                    zoomFactor = 4;
                } else if (zoomFactor == 4) {
                    zoomFactor = 8;
                } else if (zoomFactor == 8) {
                    zoomFactor = 2;
                }
                showInfo();
            }
        };
        zoomLabel.addMouseListener(factorListener);

        ActionListener zoomListener = (ActionEvent e) -> {
            pi = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
            Point p = pi.getLocation();
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(
                    p.x - (size / (2 * zoomFactor)),
                    p.y - (size / (2 * zoomFactor)),
                    (size / zoomFactor),
                    (size / zoomFactor));
            BufferedImage temp = robot.createScreenCapture(r);
            Graphics g = bi.getGraphics();
            g.drawImage(temp, 0, 0, size, size, null);
            g.setColor(new Color(255,0,0,128));
            int x = (size/2)-1;
            int y = (size/2)-1;
            g.drawLine(0,y,size,y);
            g.drawLine(x,0,x,size);
            g.dispose();
            zoomLabel.repaint();
            showInfo();
        };
        t = new Timer(40, zoomListener);
        t.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        t.stop();
    }

    public Component getGui() {
        return gui;
    }

    public void showInfo() {
        pi = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
        output.setText("Zoom: " + zoomFactor + "  Point: " + pi.getLocation());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            try {
                final ZoomOnMouse zm = new ZoomOnMouse();
                final JFrame f = new JFrame("Mouse Zoom");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
                f.add(zm.getGui());
                f.setResizable(false);
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                f.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                f.setVisible(true);

                WindowListener closeListener = new WindowAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                        zm.stop();
                        f.dispose();
                    }
                };
                f.addWindowListener(closeListener);
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: reading this code, is it correct for me to assume that this will magnify a specific area that the mouse clicks on, sort of like a zoom box?

Comment: how do I constrain it to just the application instead of the entire screen?

Comment: @user6020197 Do you know how to get the boundaries of the top level container? Do you know how to work with conditional statements? Combine the two and it should be trivial.

Comment: I do not know how to get boundaries of the top level container but I am very comfortable with conditional statements

Comment: Tip: When someone mentions a part of Java - search the docs! E.G. `getBound` in any class that extends component will find to [`Component.getBounds()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getBounds--) (and it will do so much faster than waiting for me to get back from whatever it is I am doing away from the computer).